# Zlib.Gunzip "input buffer is broken" for CSV data?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, zlib

I am writing a utility for downloading Excel files that are generated on the server and then sent to the client.  We have to handle both XLS and CSV files.  I am being asked to compress these files on the server and then decompress on the client, for which task I have decided to use the [zlib](https://github.com/imaya/zlib.js) library.

Everything goes swimmingly with the XLS files -- I am using the NPOI library for .NET which has its own method for writing the contents of my Excel workbook to a CompressionStream, and I have managed to get this work on the back and front end.

However, using the same method for CSV that I use for XLS, upon trying to decompress the data on the client side, I get the error mentioned in the title: "input buffer is broken."  The only difference is that NPOI doesn't handle CSVs, so I am using a StreamWriter to write the data via a GZipStream (in the System.IO.Compression library) instead of NPOI's Write method.  I have pasted the relevant code below.  From the below, what is it that I'm doing wrong or what needs to be done when dealing differently with these two different formats?

The server-side code (VB.NET):

```
Public Shared Function CompressCSVString(ByVal CSV As String) As List(Of Byte)
    Dim outStream As New MemoryStream()
    Dim compressionStream As New GZipStream(outStream, CompressionLevel.Optimal)
    Dim writer As New StreamWriter(compressionStream)
    writer.Write(CSV)

    Return outStream.ToArray().ToList()
End Function
```

And this is the JS code that throws the "input buffer is broken" error:

```
var decompressed = (new Zlib.Gunzip(Uint8Array.from(parameters.data))).decompress()
```

(where parameters.data is the list of bytes sent from the server)

Comment: I'm going to leave this as a comment rather than an answer, since my solution for this isn't actually an answer to the question at hand.  I ended up switching to a different zlib port at https://nodeca.github.io/pako/, and it was able to handle the same data with no problem.  So I don't know what I was doing wrong with the other zlib library, but I at least was able to solve the underlying problem.

Comment: Same for me.... I used pako and all works well..
https://www.npmjs.com/package/pako